# Are there any ways to know when one of the apps are opened?

Tags: android

I want to do a tiny service to record how many times the apps are opened.

For example, when I open the web browser, the counter of web browser will be increased.

When I open the google market, the counter of google marker will be increased.

So, how could I increase the counter for each apps when the apps are opened?